# How to use the same functions on canvases that have different background images on different pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js to manipulate different canvases with their own dimensions and background images. My problem is that I'm not sure how to continue using the below functions with new canvases with different background images (I'm stuck with one background image). I've tried creating new canvases with the following for example and controlling their backgrounds with CSS but it breaks the app on the second page:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('d');
```

I'm still learning how to work with different canvases so wasn't sure how to handle this. Thanks in advance.

**The Details:**

Right now I have 2 pages, one with:

```
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="c"></canvas>
```

and the other with:

```
<canvas width="700" height="700" id="c"></canvas>
```

They're both using this the following JavaScript and CSS:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// Upload image
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {

      //create shadow
      var shadow = {
        color: '#888888',
        blur: 70,
        offsetX: 45,
        offsetY: 45,
        opacity: 0.8
      }

      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        stroke: '#fffcf7',
        strokeWidth: 20
      }).scale(1);
      oImg.setShadow(shadow); //set shadow
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 1
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

// Add text
function Addtext() {
  canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
    // left: 0,
    // top: 0,
    fontFamily: 'helvetica neue',
    fill: '#000',
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: .2,
    fontSize: 45
  }));
}

// Delete selected object
window.deleteObject = function() {
  var activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
  if (activeGroup) {
    var activeObjects = activeGroup.getObjects();
    for (let i in activeObjects) {
      canvas.remove(activeObjects[i]);
    }
    canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    canvas.renderAll();
  } else canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
}

// Send selected object to front or back
var selectedObject;
canvas.on('object:selected', function(event) {
  selectedObject = event.target;
});
var sendtoback = function() {
  canvas.sendToBack(selectedObject);
}
var sendtofront = function() {
  canvas.bringToFront(selectedObject);
}

fabric.Object.prototype.set({
  transparentCorners: true,
  lockUniScaling: true,
  cornerColor: '#22A7F0',
  borderColor: '#22A7F0',
  cornerSize: 12,
  padding: 5
});
```

```
#c {
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/RkNFWSY.jpg);
}

.myFile {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.myFile input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**

Give your canvas (that is on the second page) a different `id` , for instance `d` ...

```
<canvas width="700" height="700" id="d"></canvas>
```

**second**

Initiate your new fabric canvas instance as such ...

```
var id = document.getElementById('c') && c ||
         document.getElementById('d') && d;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);
```

<sup>this will ensure that the appropriate canvas is present on the page</sup>

**third**

Now, set different background image for each canvas (by their id) in your css, like so ...

```
#c {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/RkNFWSY.jpg);
}
#d {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/GYpod56.jpg);
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you kindly! I appreciate the breakdown, very helpful.